# Is there a way to combine filter aggs as sub aggs?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm trying to create aggregations for certain matches.

```
GET /test_index_search
{
  "aggregations": {
    "fooAggregation": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "mu-custom-foo-agg": {
            "bool": {
              // my boolean query that searcher for `foo` matches
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "barAggregation": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "mu-custom-bar-agg": {
            "bool": {
              // my boolean query that searcher for `bar` matches
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The aggregation results that I receive are quite fine. But I'd like to combine them as sub-aggregations for convenience.

The only thing that I've found out - Elasticsearch supports Composite aggregations [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html), but CompositeSources, used as composite aggregation items do not use filter queries.

Is there any other way just to combine them into a single aggregation?

Comment: Hey darth, what is inside of the bool query?
`foo` matches and `bar` matches are looking for same field?

Comment: Both bool requests may have different filters, must / should items. It is something like a customized boolean query for `foo` and for `bar`, and content is 100% different.

Comment: If you need to use different filter values like `foo` and `bar` for different queries, the way you move forward is make sense to me. Another method is separating the queries from each other and using *multi search API*. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've also considered about moving all aggregations to a separate item of multisearch request. But it would require much more efforts then just to combine aggregations somehow. So, if there are no alternative solutions - I think I'll use that approach :)

Comment: sounds good to me :)